# Access PresentedViewController without Window

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on a framework which contains `ViewController` presentation. Wanting to test this, I tried (with Quick and Nimble):

```
expect(nav.presentedViewController).to(beAnInstanceOf(TestVC.self))
```

Within an app I can do this creating a `UIWindow` and adding the `UINavigationController` to this window (it needs to be set to visible).
In the framework I get:

```
caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "props must have a valid clientID"
```

Any ideas how to test for the correct view being presented without a window? (or how to fix this error)

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the reference of the TopViewController by making the global view controller.

**Just like that**

```
var rootViewController:UIViewController?

class MyClass1 :UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        rootViewController = self
    }
}

class MyClass2 :UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        rootViewController = self
    }
}
```

Every time rootViewController instance replace with the last `UIViewController`